# Can I walk faster?

Tags: bioshock

I'm playing my way through Bioshock (and then Bioshock 2) to prepare for Bioshock Infinite. I'm doing okay apart from I've got to a part where I have no weapons apart from a wrench and a camera. I want to shock the enemy using plasmids and then run up and whack him with my wrench, but I seem to move very slowly (this is all the time, not just in this area). Can I up my move speed at all or is there a button for sprint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research the Thuggish Splicers to obtain the [SportBoost](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/SportBoost) physical tonics, which increases movement speed and also lets you swing your wrench faster. You can use both versions of this tonic at the same time.

Comment: In Bioshock 2, the first speed boost tonic is acquired easily early on, but for the second you need to do a lot of camera research on spider splicers (the ones that climb on the roof a lot and carry hooks) and they only appear in one or two places in the game, so make sure you get it. I missed out.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are playing PC version.

Firstly check if you didn't press walk(should be CTRL) or crouch (C) buttons. So far I checked in forums thats most common problem. Otherwise it will be natural game speed.

While playing Bioshock 1 I don't remember having sprint, but in 2nd part you will be able to unlock charge with drill :D

Answer (score -3):

There's no way to move faster without tonics. I suggest taking cover, and shocking enemies at close range.